# On a UEFI install, how to do Minimal, Minimal Virtual Machine, Expert install?

Tags: server, grub2, system-installation, uefi, ubuntu-minimal

On the regular server installation boot screen, one can press <kbd>F4</kbd> to enable `Minimal` or `Minimal Virtual Machine` options, and there is also an `Expert` install option.

However, on a UEFI install boot screen, there is just a GRUB menu.

How does one enable the `Minimal Virtual Machine` and `Expert` modes via this GRUB menu?  Are there parameters one can add via editing the boot line by pressing <kbd>e</kbd>?

Thanks

[image: example of UEFI boot screen (screenshot)]

Answer (score 0):

You will get a minimal install, if you select no (extra) program package, when offered by `tasksel`. So you need not do anything at the grub menu.

See this link for more details,

[Mini system with 'text' screen user interface](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#Mini_system_with_.27text.27_screen_user_interface) - Scroll down to the pink menu.

So if you do not select anything here, and un-select whatever might be pre-selected, you will get a minimal system.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i was aware of not selecting packages to get a minimal regular install, but what about `minimal virtual machine` install?  (not a virtual machine host, a guest)

Are there manual changes I can make to the installer flags/boot options to make it tailored for a virtual environment like the regular non-UEFI installer `minimal virtual machine` option?  Also, what about the "expert mode"?  It offers more choice during installation for certain sections

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience of virtual machines running in UEFI mode. If you think that my answer stops other people from answering, I can delete my answer.